# Twelve cards are dealt from a standard deck of 52 cards. What's the probablity that all dealt cards are diamonds or hearts?

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve cards are dealt from a standard deck of 52 cards. What's the probability that all dealt cards are diamonds or hearts?

I know that there are 13 of each suit in a deck of 52 ... but I don't know it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{# of ways to have 12 cards that are all hearts or diamonds}}{\text{# of ways to have 12 cards in general}} = \frac{\binom{26}{12}}{ \binom{52}{12}} = \frac{190}{4060189}$$